# handing data to a config when running a flask app?

Tags: python, flask

I looked at a fairly generic structure to base my app off of, which looks something like this in directory structure:

```
run.py
config.py
app/
  __init__.py
  views.py
  blueprints/
  sql/
```

I put some variables in my `config.py`, which is then read by `__init__.py` when the app is made. Some pieces are completely static and don't matter, but some parts I want to be configurable on each different run. For example, `queries = [x for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(_basedir, sql_path))]` where `sql_path` is configurable, or changing the `port_number`

The absolute ideal would be to use command line arguments on the `run.py` script.
My first reaction was clearly to do the following in `run.py` to configure it:

```
from app import app
import argparse
import os

_basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='run the app')
parser.add_argument('--port', type=int, default=1225)
parser.add_argument('--sql_path', type=str, default='/app/sql/')
parser.add_argument('--debug', type=boolean, default=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

app.config['queries'] = [x for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(_basedir, args.sql_path))]
app.config['port_number'] = args.port
app.config['debug'] = args.debug

app.run(debug=args.debug, port=app.config['port_number'])
```

this will result in a `KeyError` when I run the app, saying that sql_path is not configured, as one of the blueprints uses it.

Is there a way to configure this with command line arguments? I want to be able to do `python run.py --sql_path=../sql/ --port_number=5000`, for example, and have that configure in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can do this as follows with a decorator that Flask provides:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.cli.command()
def initdb():
    """Initialize the database."""
    print 'Init the db'
```

Then on the command like call that function like so:

```
$ flask -a hello.py initdb
```

Flask uses the [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/) package to pass through command line args, so anything available there should be available from Flask as well.

`app.cli` is an instance of `click.Group` ([docs here](http://click.pocoo.org/api/?highlight=group#click.Group)) meaning things like `@click.option()` should translate over to be `@app.cli.option()` pretty nicely.

If you wanted to actually pass an option it might look something like this:

```
@app.cli.command()
@app.cli.option('--test', help='test')
def takearg(test):
    print test
```

And then call it as follows:

```
$ flask -a hello.py --test=teststring
```

Comment: The version of Flask that uses Click has yet to be released, however.